# Dropdown select component state one step behind

Tags: reactjs

I have no clue why the selected dropdown value is one step behind in the URL search params string. My url is like this: http://localhost/?dropdownsel=. Below is my code:

```
//App.js

//update params value
function setParams({ dropdownsel }) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();

  searchParams.set("dropdownsel", dropdownsel);

  return searchParams.toString();
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    dropdownsel: ""
  };
  //update url params
  updateURL = () => {
    const url = setParams({
      dropdownsel: this.state.dropdownsel
    });
    //do not forget the "?" !
    this.props.history.push(`?${url}`);
  };
  onDropdownChange = dropdownsel => {
    this.setState({ dropdwonsel: dropdownsel });
    this.updateURL();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Dropdownsel
        onChange={this.onDropdownselChange}
        value={this.state.dropdownsel}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Below is dropdownsel component code:

```
//Dropdownsel.js

const attrData = [{ id: 1, value: AA }, { id: 2, value: BB }];
class Dropdownsel extends Component {
  onDropdownChange = event => {
    this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.onDropdownChange}>
          <option value="">Select</option>
          {attrData.map(item => (
            <option key={item.id} value={item.value}>
              {" "}
              {item.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dropdownsel;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for formatting my code. I don't know how to do it every time when I post question. I figured it out myself. I need to make a call back function for updateURL() because the setState() is not executed immediately.  so my code should be revised like below:

```
onDropdownChange = (dropdownsel) => {

this.setState({ dropdwonsel:dropdownsel }, ()=>{this.updateURL();
});
```

};

Comment: Ah, great job @user788448 finding out the answer yourself. My reply is basically the same  + 1

Comment: Would you mark your answer as ✅ so it'd help others that your answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because `this.setState` is asynchronous (like a `Promise` or `setTimeout` are)

So there are two workarounds for your specific case.

### Workaround #1 - using a callback

Use the [callback option](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of `this.setState`.

When you take a look at the declaration of `setState`, it accepts an "optional" callback method, which is called when the state has been updated.

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

What it means is that, within the callback, you have an access to the updated state, which was called asynchronously behind the scene by React.

So if you call `this.updateURL()` within the callback, `this.state.dropdownsel` value will be the one you are expecting.

Instead of,

```
this.setState({ dropdwonsel: dropdownsel });
this.updateURL();
```

Call `this.updateURL` in the callback.

```
// Note: '{ dropdwonsel }' is equal to '{ dropdwonsel: dropdwonsel }'
// If your value is same as the state, you can simplify this way
this.setState({ dropdwonsel }, () => {
  this.updateURL()
});
```

### Workaround #2 - passing the new value directly

You can also pass the new value directly as an argument of `this.updateURL()` (which might make testing easier as it makes you method depend on a value, which you can fake).

```
this.setState({ dropdwonsel });
this.updateURL(dropdownsel );
```

Now your `this.updateURL` doesn't depend on the `this.state.dropdownsel`, thus you can can use the arg to push the history.

```
  //update url params
  updateURL = dropdownsel => {
    const url = setParams({
      dropdownsel
    });
    //do not forget the "?" !
    this.props.history.push(`?${url}`);
  };
```